# Google chrome - not launching from top and left 0 pixels

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, kiosk, kiosk-mode

[image]

Google Chrome Stable i am using in Windows 8.1 and in Windows 8.1 Pro from the startup path as following:

```
timeout 5 > nul
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 11 > nul
@start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

- 10% times on boot it works exactly as full-screen mode.
- BUT, 90% times on boot it does not work, it launch the Chrome but it does not launch it from top, left 0 pixel
- if i manually run that batch file then 100% time it works successfully, but when its automated then it start to mess

Can anyone please help? (i have been having this issue for about 3 months now, and its getting worst because cant find any solution yet to resolve this issue permanently)

Comment: that's obviously a bug, and you should report it to google rather than discuss it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on **windows 7 32 bits**, so i created this vbscript in order to create a shortcut in the startup folder and to launch the batch file in hidden mode.

**Shortcut4Batch.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim PathApplication,ShortcutName,VbsPath
VbsPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
PathApplication = "C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Hackoo\BAT\stackoverflow\KioskChrome.bat"
ShortcutName = "KioskChrome"
Call Shortcut(VbsPath,ShortcutName)
Call Hidden_Run(Dblquote(PathApplication))
'*********************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,StartFolder,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    StartFolder = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(StartFolder & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-25"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
Function Hidden_Run(MyProgram)
    Dim ws,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Result = ws.run(MyProgram,0,True) '0 to hide the program
    Hidden_Run = Result
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

**KioskChrome.bat**

```
@echo off
@start /b cmd /c "%programfiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Where do you apply the alignment? to tell Chrome "listen buddy, you have to run as 1280x768 on the screen top : 0px, left:0px" ?